# How do I reference the same Carrierwave uploaded file in multiple Ruby model instances without reprocessing

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

I have a model that is using Carrierwave as an uploader to  upload files to fog storage.

The problem is that when I create say 100 model objects they all upload the same file.

I need the model instances to reference the same uploaded file. A **one-to-many** relationship where there are many model instances and 1 file.

At the moment the file is an attribute called attachment on my model messages.rb -

```
 class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :remote_attachment_url, :from, :to, :status, :attachment, :campaign, :version, :user_id, :SmsId, :response, :response_code, :client_id
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
 end
```

I set attachment in my controller when I create a new Message instance in **MessagesController.rb** -

```
 recipients.each do |value|
   @message = Message.new(:attachment => params[:message][:attachment], :campaign => message[:campaign], :version => message[:version], :to => value, :body => body, :status => status, :user_id => current_user.id, :client_id => client.id )
 end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.0, Rails 4

---

## Solution:

I fixed this by pushing my attachment file into a new model then building an association between the message object and the attachment object.

**MessagesController:**

```
@attachment = Attachment.create(params[:message][:attachment_attributes])
recipients.each do |value|   
  @message = Message.new(:campaign => params[:message][:campaign], :version => params[:message][:version], :to => value, :body => params[:message][:body], :status => status, :user_id => current_user.id, :client_id => client.id )
  @message.attachment = @attachment
end
```

**Message model:**

```
 attr_accessible  :attachment_id, :attachment_attributes 
 belongs_to :attachment
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachment
```

**Attachment model:**

```
attr_accessible :attached, :remote_attached_url, :attachment_attributes
mount_uploader :attached, AttachmentUploader
```

Comment: you have to model your database to with seperate table for uploader and then assign multiple value to it using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Answer (score 0):

If in your model that mounts the carrierwave uploader you have a property:

```
mount_uploader :attachment, YourUploader
```

so assuming your new object is created, you should be able to assign the image like this:

```
newObj.attachment = anotherObj.attachment
newObj.save
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I'm getting odd behavior using this approach. I've tried creating 2 models using the approach described. 2 files got created in my remote file store. One is 20MB the other is 24b. Neither is usable.